# pandas histogram with logarithmic axes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, histogram

I have a pandas DataFrame with time length data in seconds. The length varies from seconds to months so taking a histogram after taking log is convenient as it covers the range better. Here is a sample code

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.random.lognormal(mean=10, sigma=1, size=10000)
df=pd.DataFrame(x, range(10000), columns=['timeLength'])

np.log10(df.timeLength).hist()
```

However, the labels on the x-axis are log scaled. Is there a way to put them as 10^1 and so on. Or even better, if I could put them as 1 second, 10 seconds, 1 minute, 10 minute, 1 hours, 1 day and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Non-Uniform Bin Histogram

Instead of logging the values,

> ```
> np.log10(df.timeLength)
> ```

try creating a non-uniform binning when computing the histogram.  This can be accomplished with [`np.histogram`'s `bins` argument](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Based on

> if I could put them as 1 second, 10 seconds, 1 minute, 10 minute, 1 hours, 1 day and so on.

the following bin array could be created

```
# Bin locations (time in seconds)
bins = np.array([0, 1, 10, 60, 60*10, 60*60, 24*60*60])
```

### Example

The original dataset was enlarged to fill more of the bins (`mean=5, sigma=2` instead of `mean=10, sigma=1`), this is for example only.  The non-uniform bins are defined, the histogram computed and the plot is presented.  The bins are for example and may be altered.

```
# Create random data in DataFrame
x = np.random.lognormal(mean=5, sigma=2, size=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['timeLength'])

print df.describe()
print

# Create non-uniform bins.  Unit in seconds.
bins = np.array([0, 1, 10, 60, 60*10, 60*60, 24*60*60])
print 'hisogram bins:', bins

# Get histogram of random data
y, x = np.histogram(df, bins=bins, normed=True)

# Correct bin placement
x = x[1:]

# Turn into pandas Series
hist = pd.Series(y, x)

# Plot
ax = hist.plot(kind='bar', width=1, alpha=0.5, align='center')
ax.set_title('Non-Uniform Bin Histogram')
ax.set_xlabel('Time Length')
ax.set_xticklabels(['1 s', '10 s', '1 Min', '1 Hr', '1 Day', '>1 Day'], rotation='horizontal')
```

---

```
    timeLength   
count   10000.000000
mean     1014.865417
std      4751.820312
min         0.062893
25%        36.941388
50%       144.081235
75%       556.223797
max    237838.467337

hisogram bins: [    0     1    10    60   600  3600 86400]
```

[image: non-uniform bin histogram]

Please advise if this is not the intended result.

Comment: This is exactly what I was interested in. Thanks for the detail!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use custom bins, you may want to combine [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with `.groupby().count()` and use a `bar` chart:

```
x=np.random.lognormal(mean=10, sigma=1, size=10000)
df=pd.DataFrame(x, range(10000), columns=['timeLength'])

df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.timeLength,include_lowest=True, bins=[0, 1, 10, 60, 60**2, 60**2*24, df.timeLength.max()], labels=['1s', '10s', '1min', '1hr', '1d', '>1d'])
df.groupby('bin').count().plot.bar()
```

[image]